# SQL database disaster recovery in a second datacenter using storage

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

I have the following:

Data Center (1) has a set of two Microsoft SQL Server databases. They are clustered using MSCS and shared NetApp storage FAS3250 system. This provides me with local fail-over / redundancy. I want now to extend this to a second data center, let’s call it Data Center (2). DC# 1 and DC# 2 and connected to a flat high speed network, so we can share the same IP subnet between the two data centers.  In DC# 2 there is another Microsoft SQL Server database connected to another NetApp storage FAS3250 system.  Here are my questions:

1. I wanted DC# 2 to be my disaster recovery for the SQL Server database.
2. I wanted the solution to be based on NetApp solution using SQL standard
3. Need to make sure any ODBC connections and client connections are now migrated to the SQL database server in DC#2

Any thoughts or ideas to make this happen?  Thanks,

Skaher

Comment: Are you using Enterprise or Standard edition of SQL Server? If standard, your options are limited of course.

Comment: Standard edition only

Answer (score 1):

With a standard edition you basically have two options, log shipping and mirroring.  Unfortunately, neither of these solutions gives you an automated or managed solution for your third requirement of migrating connections.  However, you could base connections on a set of configuration files and swap them out for a "failover" scenario.

If you can swing an Enterprise upgrade, AvailabilityGroups become a much better holistic solution for data and connections.  You have both hardware and data redundancy and connections to the database server are managed via a listener service, directing database requests to the active server.  Downtime is almost non-existent.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the feedback.  Enterprise is defiantly the better option here and standard edition will limit my options, but I was thinking of using the NetApp for mirroring the data and using the NetApp tools to manage it such as snapmirror and snapmanager.  We could write some scripts to help with the migration.  Any thoughts or feedback on that option?  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with NetApp and can't really speak to the best way to go about it that way.  The major concern here is going to be PIT recovery.  So if you can manage the mirror in such a way to keep from corrupting your databases, I don't see it as a problem.